# When renaming files in Ubuntu 13.1, the label is too dark until edit is complete

Tags: 13.10

Fresh install of Ubuntu 13.1.  When renaming files, the labels are too dark to see until the label edit is finished - then the file label can be seen properly.  The background is dark and the characters are dark making the edit very hard to see.  How can this be changed?  Is there a setting in the file manager?  I have not found a setting to fix this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A bug that's been around since start of 13.10 dev

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1236601